# How to index interfaces with an array of strings in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an object with type `Test` below. I am only interested in certain keys of that object, so I created an array of strings. I then looped through these keys of interest and attempt to access the obj using the bracket notation.

```
interface Test {
  field1: {
    subfield1: string;
    subfield2: string;
    ...
  };
  field2: string;
  field3: number;
  ....
}

const obj: Test = {
  field1: {
    subfield1: 'hello',
    subfield2: 'world',
    ...
  },
  ...
}

const keysOfInterest = ['field1', 'field3', ...]

keysOfInterest.forEach((key) => {
  if (obj[key] === 'Some condition') {
    // Perform some logic
  }
})
```

But typescript is giving me an error `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Test'.`. I'd still like to get the intellisense provided.

Thank you.

Comment: the "Omit" utility type could help you : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys
You could define your "obj" without some keys from Test type you are not interested in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work only when you set type of `keysOfInterest` to `(keyof Test)[]`.

```
interface Test {
  field1: {
    subfield1: string;
    subfield2: string;
  };
  field2: string;
  field3: number;
}


const obj: Test = {
  field1: {
    subfield1: 'hello',
    subfield2: 'world',
  },
  field2: 'f2',
  field3:  3
}

const keysOfInterest: (keyof Test)[]  =  ["field1", "field2"]


keysOfInterest.forEach((key) => {
    const v = obj[key] // no errors
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwLABQyyMwEANgCYCMAXLoccRgK4BGpFN9WUoA5gG5GTVhzJUATDzB8QQkQF9hREhMrTkvASuKcqAZnogWAWzbQViwjYIIA9iCzJ7bAFb10zgLwNV+7j8mLXYAumQAcgALCnJ7CIAaEWZQ9U0IgHd7KCpEpST-NPoImEk8wq4jYgNCawJCBydsAGt6ZAAKZogAT3sYNEwwAEoAbQBdYl9kEYAiMJmE5Dm0mbHbQmaAOhhsgFFEKPbOnqHkbwA+IKZG5wA3M5d3Ea7utYJFIaA)

Comment: You're answer helped. Modified it further by using the `Pick` type. Thank you!